# Image not loading for image

Tags: ios, objective-c, input-button-image

I just want to set image for a `UIButton` and created an `IBOutlet` for it. I have a loader above it, when the images are loaded then loader will stop and will assign a new image for that button. When code is called, the placeholder images remains and url images are not loaded

```
  [_Image1 sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrayGallery valueForKey:@"link"][0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blurred-background"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        [_ImageLoader1 stopAnimating];
        [_ImageLoader1 removeFromSuperview];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using completion block to download image from url. So you need to do as per below.

```
 [_Image1 sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrayGallery valueForKey:@"link"][0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blurred-background"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

            [_Image1 setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];//Don't forgot to check for error if error is nil or image is not nil then only set image

            [_ImageLoader1 stopAnimating];
            [_ImageLoader1 removeFromSuperview];
  }];
```

Comment: can't use ' _Image1.image = image' for a button

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a completion block for `SDWebImageCache` ,Set image inside the completion block

```
[_Image1 sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrayGallery valueForKey:@"link"][0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blurred-background"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        _Image1.image = image;
        [_ImageLoader1 stopAnimating];
        [_ImageLoader1 removeFromSuperview];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

update image in main thread try something like this

```
 [_Image1 sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrayGallery valueForKey:@"link"][0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blurred-background"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        [_ImageLoader1 stopAnimating];
        [_ImageLoader1 removeFromSuperview];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           _Image1.image = image;   
        });

 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

get `NSData` from `NSUrlRequest` and from `NSUrl URLWithString` "your url"

and convert `NSData` to `UIImage` and set background image.

Answer (score 0):

First get the image url and check the image url length is greater than zero / not `null`. And make sure the image url is working correctly or not. Hit the `url` on `Browser` and check are you getting proper image.

`SDWebImage` library is updating the button image, But that's not happening on `Main Thread`. This might be the reason for not updating `backgroundImage` of the `UIButton`.

```
- (void)sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:(nullable NSURL *)url
forState:(UIControlState)state
placeholderImage:(nullable UIImage *)placeholder
options:(SDWebImageOptions)options
completed:(nullable SDExternalCompletionBlock)completedBlock {
    if (!url) {
        [self.imageURLStorage removeObjectForKey:@(state)];
        return;
    }

    NSString *imageURL = [arrayGallery valueForKey:@"link"][0];
    self.imageURLStorage[@(state)] = url;

    __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
    [self sd_internalSetImageWithURL:url
                    placeholderImage:placeholder
                             options:options
                        operationKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UIButtonBackgroundImageOperation%@", @(state)]
                       setImageBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSData *imageData) {
                           [weakSelf setBackgroundImage:image forState:state];
                       }
                            progress:nil
                           completed:completedBlock];
}
```

Stop `loader` animation and set `UIButton` background image on `main thread`.

```
NSString *imageURL = [arrayGallery valueForKey:@"link"][0];

if (imageURL.length > 0) {

    [_Image1 sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blurred-background"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [_ImageLoader1 stopAnimating];
            [_ImageLoader1 removeFromSuperview];
            [_Image1 setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        });
    }];

}
```